# .addClass when #mainNav :visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, visible

**Desired:**
When menu button is clicked and navigation(#mainNav) slides in, check to see if visible. If so, .addClass .is-open to .nav-item. When navigation (#mainNav) is closed, .removeClass .is-open from .nav-item.

**Issue:**
Class is not being added to .nav-item when navigation is visible(Slides).

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <!-- Logo and Burger -->
  <div class="brand-wrap">
    <div class="trigger-wrapper">
      <button id="burger">
        <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
        <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
        <div class="nav-trigger-line"></div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Logo and Burger -->

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar main-nav">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="company.html" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-number">01.</span><br>Our Company</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="people.html" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-number">02.</span><br>Our People</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="services.html" class="nav-link">
            <span class="nav-number">03.</span>
            <br>Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="careers.html" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-number">04.</span><br>Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link"><span class="nav-number">05.</span><br>Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navigation -->
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
 .brand-wrap {
      position: fixed;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    #burger {
      float: right;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .trigger-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
    }

    .main-nav a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .main-nav {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: rgba(35, 31, 32, 1);
    }

    .nav-container {
      margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .nav-link {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: .25em 1em;
    }

    .nav-link:hover {
      color: #82bc00;
    }

    .nav-number {
      font-size: .5em;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    .nav-trigger-line {
      height: 3px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 6px auto;
    }
```

**JS**

```
// Menu click function
$('#burger').click(function() {
  $('#mainNav').toggle();
});

// Check if Nav is visible
if ($('#mainNav').is(':visible')) {
  $(".nav-container .nav .nav-item").addClass("is-open");
} else {
  $(".nav-container .nav .nav-item").removeClass("is-open");
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/auszo29m/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send it **inside the event handler**:

```
// Menu click function
$('#burger').click(function() {
  $('#mainNav').toggle(function () {
    // Check if Nav is visible
    if ($('#mainNav').is(':visible')) {
      $(".nav-container .nav .nav-item").addClass("is-open");
    } else {
      $(".nav-container .nav .nav-item").removeClass("is-open");
    }
  });
});
```

The best thing you can do is, you should put it inside the callback function like above.